# How to structure a Referer Statistics Database Table?

Tags: database, database-design, statistics, database-schema

I'm wondering what would be a good structure for a Referer Statistics Table. I mean, I got many users. I give them a Referer System and want to show them proper Statistics (for example the monthly / daily amount of clicks and refered users). How would You do this?

Best regards, .wired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a table that holds the raw data. Then, create materialized views for the different aggregation levels. If your RDBMS doesn't support them, create aggregation tables manually.

If performance is not a concern, don't bother creating aggregation tables. You can use simple views in this case which will save you development effort.